# How to add functionality to existing classes?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

Currently, I am developing an android library. Basically the idea is to add some functionality to any android widget that there is. The library is used to create compound views, and the user should be able to convert every existing android widget/view into a compound view with some additional functionality I want to add dynamically.

Every one of these views should still be useable inside XML files, which means I cannot change the constructor too much.

Another requirement is that I need an option for the user to provide some classes for the views. By that, I mean that the created compound view is going to have a public variable named viewStore. Thy type of viewStore would either be the user's implementation of the ViewStore interface (preferred way but I am pretty sure this would require code generation as discussed later) or would be provided via generics.

In the end, a compound view would have this folder structure like this:

- MyView Folder

  - MyView extends CoolViewWithViewStore extends AndroidWidgetChoosenByUser
  - MyViewStore implements ViewStore <- used in CoolViewWithViewStore

One option is to extend every single widget. I don't think I need to explain why this is a bad idea. Furthermore the user couldn't provide the additional classes that are needed.

Another one I thought of was Annotation with code generation. The problem I came across here was that the user needs access to variables of CoolViewWithViewStore inside MyView which wouldn't be possible because CoolViewWithViewStore would be generated at compile-time and furthermore the user could accidentally use his class inside XML instead of our generated one.

I would like to hear if anybody has a better idea of how to handle this or if there even is a clean solution to this to achieve this kind of architecture. If anybody has a better idea of how to structure my library I would like to hear this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Kotlin extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) you could extend a class with new functionality without having to inherit from the class.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer but if I got extension functions correct you can add variables wit getters and methods but cannot add variables with backing fields

Comment: Yes.  Extension property can't have a backing field @MaxGierlachowski